# Ncurses compile error with Visuald - undefined symbol initscr

Tags: d, ncurses

I created a ncurses dub package project using `dub init testnc`. Then, I used `dub generate visuald` in `testnc` folder to create a VisualD project.
I've fixed the lib path to `.dub\lib` and name to `ncursesd-d.lib` (as generated by dub).

When I try to compile (the simplest test I could think for curses library linking).

```
import deimos.ncurses.ncurses;
void main()
{
    initscr();
}
```

I get the following error

```
Erro    1   Error 42: Symbol Undefined _initscr D:\Repos\testnc\
```

I've also tried changing `deimos.ncurses.ncurses` to `deimos.ncurses.curses` and to `deimos.ncurses` to no avail.

Any ideas?

**Visual Studio 2013 - update 4
VisualD - 0.3.38
D 2.066.1**

Comment: You will need to link to the ncurses library. But as you are on Windows (and I have little experience with ncurses on Windows), you will have to look around to find the library.

Comment: It is straightforward to build ncurses in MSYS2 or Cygwin, and pretty easy to use it in your D application that you build in these two environments. Using it in the Visual Studio is a different story I guess...

Comment: I thought the resulting ncurses.lib generated by dub build ncurses, or its project ncurses, in VS, would be such library!?
I linked it on project properties, as well as its path (.dub\lib).

Comment: @DejanLekic Do you mean building the regular ncurses? If so, I could maybe try that.

Comment: The deimos project only provides bindings to the libraries and does not provide the libraries themselves. You will need to get/compile the ncurses library and link against it for things to work.

Comment: @orlando2bjr yes. Regular ncurses build straight from the MSYS2 environment. :)

Comment: I'm having some issues installing msys2 (connection servers), but I'll try again later @DejanLekic and will let you know if I get it right.

Comment: Just so I understand it right, @yaz, the ncursesd.lib I get from "building" deimos' project using dub is not what I should link, right? Out of curiosity, what is that for, then?

Comment: No good with MSYS2. Probably I'm noobieing at it. I got a msys-ncurses++w6.dll built and added it to the project. I'll leave it to that for now, till thursday or later because of work, and then try again :-/
Thanks for the inputs, though.